# schedule in node js on date

Tags: mysql, angularjs, node.js

i want to create scheduler in Node Js to call service and send email to particular request.

release date =20/03/2017

scheduler are 2 month 1 month and 15 days before release date.
i tried this below please provide me better solution
function checkRelease(){

```
var date = '2017-11-18T07:05:32.950Z';
var release = new Date(date);
console.log(release);
var current = new Date();
console.log(current);
var timeDifference = Math.abs(release.getTime() - current.getTime());
console.log(timeDifference);
var differentDays = Math.ceil(timeDifference / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
console.log(differentDays);

if(differentDays === 1){
    console.log("1 day");
} else if(differentDays === 15){
    console.log("15 day");
} else if(differentDays === 28 || differentDays === 29 || differentDays === 30 || differentDays === 31){
    console.log("1 month");
} else if(differentDays === 58 || differentDays === 59 || differentDays === 60 || differentDays === 61 || differentDays === 62){        
    console.log("2 month");
}
```

}

var schedule = require('node-schedule');
var job = schedule.scheduleJob({hour: 10, minute: 0}, function(){
      checkRelease();`this function check the difference of time and call service

1. List item

   `
   });

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: scheduler call daily, so i need to check current date and find difference.

Comment: function checkRelease(){

 var date = '2017-11-18T07:05:32.950Z';
 var release = new Date(date);
 console.log(release);
 var current = new Date();
 console.log(current);
 var timeDifference = Math.abs(release.getTime() - current.getTime());
 console.log(timeDifference);
 var differentDays = Math.ceil(timeDifference / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
 console.log(differentDays);
 if(differentDays === 1){
  console.log("1 day");
 } else if(differentDays === 28 || differentDays === 29 || differentDays === 30 || differentDays === 31){
  console.log("1 month")
 }

Comment: You seem to not have doing any search effort before posting you question. Please, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to improuve the quality of you question and edit it.

Comment: Please don't put example code in comments. Instead [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
relDate ="2017-11-21T20:58:00.000Z";
var current = new Date();
console.log(current);
var timeDifference = Math.abs(relDate.getTime() - current.getTime());
var differentDays = Math.ceil(timeDifference / (1000 * 3600 *24));
console.log(differentDays);
if(differentDays === 1){
console.log("1 day");
} else if(differentDays === 15){
console.log("15 day");
} else if(differentDays === 28 || differentDays === 29 || differentDays === 
30 || differentDays === 31){
console.log("1 month");
} else if(differentDays === 58 || differentDays === 59 || differentDays === 
60 || differentDays === 61 || differentDays === 62){                 
console.log("2 month");
}
**output**
1 day

i call this function inside scheduler in app.js

//---Sechduler for release and roration date
var job = schedule.scheduleJob({hour: 18, minute:54}, function(){
        checkRelease();`call function`

});
```